# Range.getValues() fails with valid cell (Service error: Spreadsheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that's been run daily for at least the past year which has suddenly started failing (seemingly at random).

It fails when trying to call getValue() on a range that contains one cell. The code looks like this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var configSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Config");
Logger.log(configSheet);
Logger.log(configSheet.getRange(3,2));
Logger.log(configSheet.getRange(3,2).getValue());
```

It always fails on the last step with "Service error: Spreadsheets" on that line (which isn't particularly helpful as far as error messages go). Any ideas?

Other notes:

- One interesting thing is that it runs for quite a while before giving up and raising this error (longer than a single read of a single cell range should take).
- Changing the range doesn't help.
- Other spreadsheets that perform a similar step are running fine.

Answer (score 1):

It started working again in a few hours with no intervention (same code as it used to be). I'll close this out - if anyone else has this problem, it's worth seeing if it eventually goes away (I believe it might be an internal problem).

Answer (score 0):

what triggers the script to run?

You might try:

[openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

in lieu of getActiveSpreadsheet()

Comment: Just got back to this and wanted to try your suggestion but it's working again with no changes from the original. Might have been an internal problem.